# Using attributes with Managed Extensibility Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef

I want to refactor my MVC project using a plugin architecture (MEF) and i'm in the start of my way.
I have global authorization via

```
filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

Well some of the controllers should be public and previously i just used attribute [AllowAnonymous] for this. Now i move some controllers into separate plugins and they looks like this:

```
[Export("LinkedDocument", typeof(IController))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class LinkedDocumentController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

Now when i request my page i get redirected to my login page which isn't intended. If i authorize on my site it works fine, so i think i miss some configurations or so. It's first time i'm using MEF in my project.

My Application_Start is:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var pluginFolders = new List<string>();

        var plugins = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Modules")).ToList();

        plugins.ForEach(s =>
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(s);
            pluginFolders.Add(di.Name);
        });

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //Loads assemblies
        Bootstrapper.Compose(pluginFolders);

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        //ControllerFactory get's aproppriate controler
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MefControllerFactory());
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MefViewEngine(pluginFolders));
    }
```

Bootstrapper loads assemblies with controllers. It's code is:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    //..
    public static T GetInstance<T>(string contractName = null)
    {
        var type = default(T);
        if (CompositionContainer == null) return type;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contractName))
            type = CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>(contractName);
        else
            type = CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>();

        return type;
    }

    public static void Compose(List<string> pluginFolders)
    {
      //..
    }
}
```

And, finally, MefControllerFactory is:

```
public class MefControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    //..

    public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = Bootstrapper.GetInstance<IController>(controllerName);

        if (controller == null)
            throw new Exception("Controller not found!");

        return controller;
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind there are some controllers that contains both actions that requires authorization and actions that don't.